# Add a week to an SQL value stored in YYYMMDD format

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, datetime

I currently have WordPress Advanced Custom Field dates stored in my database as timestamps but due to requirements from a new plugin, I now have to store them as YYYYMMDD format.

I have a chronjob set to run each night that adds a week (604800) to each weekly event on my site where the 'event_date' is less than the current UNIX_TIMESTAMP. This republishes the event for the following week.

I'm assuming I'll need to convert the YYYYMMDD format to timestamp, add the 604800 then convert it back but really not sure how to go about it (SQL is not my strong point!)

The current SQL I have to add 604800 to the timestamp of each post with category ID of 29 (weekly) and to add 1209600 to category ID of 19 (fortnightly) is as follows...

CODE BELOW HAS BEEN UPDATED AND IS WORKING!

> ```
> UPDATE wp_postmeta rh
>
> INNER JOIN (
>     SELECT ID, wt.term_id
>     FROM wp_terms wt
>     INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy wtt ON wt.term_id = wtt.term_id
>     INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships wpr ON wpr.term_taxonomy_id = wtt.term_taxonomy_id
>     INNER JOIN wp_posts ON ID = wpr.object_id 
>     WHERE taxonomy = 'category'
>       AND (wt.term_id=32)
>       AND post_type = 'post'
>     ) t ON rh.post_id = t.ID
>  SET rh.meta_value = CASE 
>    WHEN t.term_id = 32 
>    THEN DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(rh.meta_value, '%Y%m%d') + INTERVAL 1 WEEK, '%Y%m%d')
>    ELSE rh.meta_value END
>
> WHERE rh.meta_key = 'event_date' AND rh.meta_value < UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
> ```

Would anybody be able to suggest the best way of adding a week (or fortnight) to these events that are now stored in YYYYMMDD format?

This needs to be stored in a PHP script so I can set a chronjob to execute and update this automatically every night.

Thanks in advance,
Mark.

Comment: the event_date data type is a varchar ?

Comment: the meta_value for the meta_key of event_date is stored as longtext

Comment: Yes, this is a typical problem with the `wp_postmeta` key / value store.  The values are all text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have something like `20170901` and you want to add a week to it, try this in SQL.

```
 DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(date_text_col, '%Y%m%d') + INTERVAL 1 WEEK, '%Y%m%d')
```

This will convert your text to a `DATETIME`. Then it will add the week. Then it will convert it back to text.

This should work correctly on any texty data type (CLOB, VARCHAR, CHAR).

The result of that date computation should be placed directly into the column, not added to the column. An expression like this should do it.

```
SET rh.meta_value = CASE 
       WHEN t.term_id = 32 
       THEN DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(rh.meta_value, '%Y%m%d') + INTERVAL 1 WEEK, '%Y%m%d')
       ELSE rh.meta_value END
```

If you do `rh.meta_value = rh.meta_value + (some date)` you're adding the date to itself as if it were a number, which makes no sense.

The layout of `wp_postmeta` combined with MySQL's automatic coercing of text to numbers can make this sort of thing very confusing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I've had a go at modifying my SQL query above to incorporate your code but not sure if I've followed it right. It's updated the value 'event_date' but it's not added a week... It changed it from 20170906 to 40341819!

`SET rh.meta_value = rh.meta_value + CASE WHEN t.term_id = 32 THEN DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(rh.meta_value, '%Y%m%d') + INTERVAL 1 WEEK, '%Y%m%d') END`

(I've changed the term_id (category) to 32 and given one of my posts that category so it's only updating that one for testing)

Comment: Please see my edit.   `40341819` is `20170906` + `20170913`.

Comment: Spot on mate, works perfectly!
Marked as answered and thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP, it's very easy, select the rows from your db, loop through, and then update:

```
<?php

$date = new DateTime('2014-09-18 00:00:00'); // populate with row value!
$date->modify('+1 week');
echo $date->format('Ymd');
```

Which will output `20140925`. Then update your row. See it here https://3v4l.org/5e8fg

Also, check out `DateTime::createFromFormat()`
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php to instantiate the DateTime from a different format.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need to be able to update the values stored in the database rather than just displaying the value + 1 week on the front end

Comment: Yes, well fetch the rows, manipulate the DateTime, and instead of echoing it, use `$date->format() ` in an `UPDATE` statement

Answer (score 0):

If you have a column store as varchar you could use date_add and str_to_date

```
 select  DATE_ADD(str_to_date(your_column, '%Y%m%d'),INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
 from my_table
```

Comment: The meta_value for the meta_key of event_date is stored as longtext. Would this still work?

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly a comment - but it's a bit long.

> but due to requirements from a new plugin, I now have to store them as YYYYMMDD format.

Given that they are stored as YYYMMDD in a date attribute type, I am guessing you really mean that you think you need to use an integer or character data type. In which case......OMG, WTF?

1. as you have already discovered, this makes maintaining the data a *lot* harder
2. that you have existing data to update implies that something else in your system is making use of this attribute - are you sure that everything else using this attribute is being retired?

On checking the [Wordpress site](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_postmeta), I see that the fault is actually in Wordpress which uses a really nasty EAV table design. Although I don't expect the designers ever expected the data to be used in the way this plugin / your applications does.

The DBMS can do the maths if the data is in the right format (and more correctly than your current method of adding seconds) so you just need to convert the stored data to a date, and then convert back for writing:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta rh
INNER JOIN (....) t ON rh.post_id = t.ID
SET rh.meta_value = DATE_FORMAT(
      STR_TO_DATE(rh.meta_value, '%Y%m%d') + INTERVAL 
      CASE WHEN t.term_id = 29 THEN 7 DAY
           WHEN t.term_id = 19 THEN 14 DAY 
      END, '%Y%m%d')
```

Comment: That looked so promising but it didn't work, can't be far off though! I've updated the original code to incorporate your suggestion (removed the fortnightly part to try and simplify a bit and changed the category id to 32 so it didn't effect all my posts). I'll keep fiddling but if you can see anything obvious any suggestions would be more than welcome.